#  How to display a jquery grid on clicking on row in the other grid?

Tags: jquery

How can I display a second grid on clicking on a row from the first grid?

Comment: What grid? Any sample code/markup? Where's the data coming from?

Comment: Thanks for your replay,, data is coming from DB2 I can display the data correctly in the grid, but the problem I am facing here is on row click on first grid I need to call the other funcation in the script to display second grid under the first grid..

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code/markup to reference. But, just for any generic grid (I assume you mean table) and row, maybe this could help?

```
$('#firstGrid tr:first').click(function() {
    $('#secondGrid').show();
});
```